# Constant "Error: Could not load plugin: Plugin reinitialization required" in Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm having this issue in Jenkis job:

```
+ terraform --version
Terraform v0.15.5

+ rm -rf .terraform/
+ rm -f .terraform.lock.hcl
+ terraform init -upgrade -reconfigure
Upgrading modules...
...

Initializing the backend...

Successfully configured the backend "s3"! Terraform will automatically
use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.

Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding hashicorp/aws versions matching "~> 3.0"...
- Using hashicorp/aws v3.75.2 from the shared cache directory

...

Terraform has been successfully initialized!

...

+ terraform plan -var-file qa-up.tfvars -out=tfplan
╷
│ Error: Could not load plugin
│ 
│ 
│ Plugin reinitialization required. Please run "terraform init".
│ 
│ Plugins are external binaries that Terraform uses to access and manipulate
│ resources. The configuration provided requires plugins which can't be
│ located,
│ don't satisfy the version constraints, or are otherwise incompatible.
│ 
│ Terraform automatically discovers provider requirements from your
│ configuration, including providers used in child modules. To see the
│ requirements and constraints, run "terraform providers".
│ 
│ failed to instantiate provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws" to
│ obtain schema: the cached package for registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws
│ 3.75.2 (in .terraform/providers) does not match any of the checksums
│ recorded in the dependency lock file


script returned exit code 1
```

The providers (local):

```
$ terraform providers

Providers required by configuration:
.
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws]
└── module.elasticache
    └── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws] ~> 3.0

Providers required by state:

provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws]
```

But once run locally (assuming terraform version is also 0.15.5), there is no such issue. What could be the reason of it and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you add the providers block to the question? Are you using a mixed environment with different CPU architectures?

Comment: @MarkoE question updated

Comment: If you are working in a mixed environment (e.g., MacOS, Windows, Linux), take a look here: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/providers/lock#specifying-target-platforms.

Comment: @MarkoE Linux only is used

Comment: @Marco, but I'm not 100% sure there's no someone using this repo locally on winblows - good catch!

Comment: @MarkoE comment sounds like the most lilkely root cause except the pipeline is executing `rm -f .terraform.lock.hcl` and then initializing successfully. This means the retrieved plugins may not be the plugins utilized later. Can you share the relevant `steps` block for the pipeline code also?

Comment: @MarkoE, the issue is solved by lock update and removal of `rm -f .terraform.lock.hcl`. Thanks! Make it an answer and I upvote it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue tends to happen when there are multiple CPU architectures being used. The `terraform init` command will download the provider binary for the underlying CPU architecture and create a corresponding `.terraform.lock.hcl` file. In order to make it work in a mixed environment, there is a command that can be used to avoid the issue [1]:

```bash
terraform providers lock \
  -platform=windows_amd64 \ # 64-bit Windows
  -platform=darwin_amd64 \  # 64-bit macOS
  -platform=linux_amd64     # 64-bit Linux
```

For M1 MacOS it would be `-platform=darwin_arm64`. Since it seems there is some kind of caching involved, removing the old lock file and using the new one should help.

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/providers/lock#specifying-target-platforms

Comment: Actually, the problem appeared next day again and the solution was to delete lock at all which fixed the issue

Comment: So deleting the lock file helped or it didn't help? Does any part of my answer help? Do I need to edit it?

Comment: As I said: "the solution was to delete lock at all which fixed the issue". Unfortunately, your solution didn't help, but thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me:

```bash
terraform state replace-provider   registry.terraform.io/-/template  registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/template
terraform state replace-provider   registry.terraform.io/-/aws  registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws
```

Source: [upgrade from 0.12 to 0.13: Failed to instantiate provider “registry.terraform.io/-/aws” to obtain](https://cloudaffaire.com/faq/upgrade-from-0-12-to-0-13-failed-to-instantiate-provider-registry-terraform-io-aws-to-obtain/)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I just got this when running `terraform -plugin-dir=…` (or running on nix with `terraform.withPlugins`) if you put multiple versions in the plugin dir e.g. terraform-provider-aws_v1.41.0, terraform-provider-aws_v2.70.4:

```
$ terraform init
Terraform has been successfully initialized!
…

$ terraform validate
Error: Could not satisfy plugin requirements


Plugin reinitialization required. Please run "terraform init".
…
Error: provider.aws: new or changed plugin executable
```

Apparently, `terraform init` writes the sha256sums to .terraform/plugins/darwin_arm64/lock.json, but `terraform validate` picks a different binary within `-plugin-dir` and errors that it has changed.

If you are using `-plugin-dir` with terraform 0.12, make sure there is only one version of each provider type.